# while debugging, stop when a variable changes its value

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to stop the execution of a script when a variable (say, an iterator like 'i'), changes its value?

Of course, I know you can set a breakpoint at some lines, but I would want just to set a variable, and when it changes, stop the program for debuggin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `debugger`, something like:

```js
function testDebugger() {
  var i = 10;
  while(i--) {
    if (i === 5) debugger;
    Logger.log(i);
  }
}
```

Remember to start from the editor, with "Debug" and not "Run".

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible. However if you use a wrapper like a setValue method you can do as the answer above me, or throw "hello" and it will break into the debugger too.